# Eigenvector discontinuities in hermitian matrix diagonalization

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77, intel-fortran

I need to diagonalize a 2x2 Hermitian matrix that depends on a parameter x, which varies continuously. For diagonalization I use EISPACK. When I plot the real and imaginary components of eigenvectors as a function of x, I notice that they have discontinuities. The eigenvalues calculation is OK. When I plot the eigenvectors in Maxima, the solutions appear continuous. I need the continuous eigenvectors since in next step I will need to calculate their derivatives.

Below the f77 code I use as test (compiling with gfortran on mingw).

```
program Eigenvalue

  implicit none

  integer n, m 
  parameter (n=2)
  integer  ierr, matz, i, j 
  double precision x, dx, xf, amp, xin 
  double precision w(n)
  double precision Ar(n,n), Ai(n,n)
  double precision xr(n,n), xi(n,n)
  double precision fm1(2,n)   ! f77
  double precision fv1(n)     ! f77 
  double precision fv2(n)     ! f77       
  double complex psi1a, psi1b, psi2a, psi2b 

  m = 51              

  xf  = 10.d0  
  xin = 0.0d0     

  amp = 2.d0 
  dx = (xf - xin)/(m-1)

  do i = 1, m     
  x = dx*(i-m) + xf   

  Ar(1,1) = dsin(x)**2
  Ar(1,2) = amp*dcos(x)
  Ar(2,1) = amp*dcos(x)
  Ar(2,2) = dcos(x)**2

  Ai(1,1) = 0.0d0
  Ai(1,2) = amp*dsin(x)  
  Ai(2,1) = -amp*dsin(x) 
  Ai(2,2) = 0.0d0

  matz = 1

  call ch ( n, n, ar, ai, w, matz, xr, xi, fv1, fv2, fm1, ierr ) !f77

  write(20,*) x, w(1), w(2)

  write(21,*) x, xr(1,1), xi(1,1)
  write(22,*) x, xr(2,1), xi(2,1)

  write(23,*) x, xr(1,2), xi(1,2)
  write(24,*) x, xr(2,2), xi(2,2)       

!     autovetor 1

  psi1a = cmplx(xr(1,1),xi(1,1)) 
  psi1b = cmplx(xr(1,2),xi(1,2)) 

!     autovetor 2 

  psi2a = cmplx(xr(2,1),xi(2,1)) 
  psi2b = cmplx(xr(2,2),xi(2,2))         

  end do
  end
```

Comment: So, how do the results look like? How do the discontinuities look like? What is the purpose of units 20, 21, 22, 23 and 24 in your program? (you do not open them anywhere)

Comment: Why do you have the [tag:intel-fortran] tag? Did you use it?

Comment: I have checked your code using EISPACK and I get sensible results.
I have checked those results against a more modern version of your code using LAPACK. 

The only time I found anything that suggested discontinuities was when I accidently mixed single and double precision numbers.

Comment: @muddle thanks for checking my code. Please, can you share the modern version of my code with LAPACK ?.

Comment: What do you mean by discontinuities? Eigenvectors have an arbitrary complex phase which may well vary apparently randomly  through your results. I have seen this in other cases, there is nothing wrong with the eigenvectors, only your assumption that the phase stays constant. Quite how do you want to use the evecs? If your final solution depends upon the phase its more than likely that something is wrong with your formulation - or that in the final equation the phase somehow cancels out.

Comment: Oh, and your program is not f77 as it uses free format and implicit none (thank god!) - but in style it is a bizarre mixture of f66, f77 and f90, please don't use dcos and similar, it should have stopped being used 40 years ago, cos is perfectly fine. And are you aware that the way you are using the cmplx function is probably losing precision?

Comment: @IanBush Thanks for your comments and suggestions. In relation to discontinuities: the values of some components of the eigenvectors suddenly change between two adjacent values of x. This behavior is not observed when I compute the eigenvectors analytically using Maxima, where the components oscillate smoothly as a function of x.
I must calculate the numerical derivative of the eigenvector components as a function of x, but at the singularities the derivative diverges and introduces errors in my calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not really an answer, what follows is the code I used with LAPACK. 
I used the latest versions of LAPACK and BLAS, with the following compiler options:

gfortran -Og -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra {location_of_lapack}/liblapack.a {location_of_blas}/blas_LINUX.a main.f90 -o main

I'm compiling on Mac OS X with gfortran 6.3.0 from homebrew.

As Ian mentioned above, things like dcos are replaced with cos and I have used the KIND= formulation to ensure the same precision.

Ian also mentioned above about the arbitrary phase. 
This problem is answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-get-eigenvectors-without-phase-jump); I have translated this solution into my code below. 
The "magic" happens after the call to ZHEEV.

With this fix, I see no discontinuities.

```
program Eigenvalue
  !> This can be used with the f2008 call
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
  implicit none

  !> dp contains the kind value for double precision.
  !> Use below if compiling to f2008
  integer, parameter :: dp = REAL64
  !> Use below if compiling with f95 up and comment out iso_fortran_env
  !>integer, parameter :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15, 300)
  !> Set wp to the desired precision.
  integer, parameter :: wp = dp

  integer, parameter :: n = 2
  integer :: i, j, k, m
  real(kind=wp) x, dx, xf, amp, xin 
  real(kind=wp), dimension(n) ::  w
  real(kind=wp), dimension(n, n) ::  Ar, Ai
  complex(kind=wp), dimension(n, n) :: A
  complex(kind=wp), dimension(max(1,2*n-1)) :: WORK
  integer, parameter :: lwork = max(1,2*n-1)
  real(kind=wp), dimension(max(1, 3*n-2)) :: RWORK
  integer :: info
  complex(kind=wp) ::  psi1a, psi1b, psi2a, psi2b 
  real(kind=wp) :: mag
  m = 51              

  xf  = 10.0_wp
  xin = 0.0_wp   

  amp = 2.0_wp

  if (m .eq. 1) then
     dx = 0.0_wp
  else
     dx = (xf - xin)/(m-1)
  end if

  do i = 1, m
     x = dx*(i-m) + xf   

     Ar(1,1) = sin(x)**2
     Ar(1,2) = amp*cos(x)
     Ar(2,1) = amp*cos(x)
     Ar(2,2) = cos(x)**2

     Ai(1,1) = 0.0_wp
     Ai(1,2) = amp*sin(x)  
     Ai(2,1) = -amp*sin(x) 
     Ai(2,2) = 0.0_wp

     do j = 1, n
        do k = 1, n
           A(j, k) = cmplx(Ar(j, k), Ai(j, k), kind=wp)
        end do
     end do
     call ZHEEV('V', 'U', N, A, N, W, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, INFO)
     do j = 1, n
        A(:, j) = A(:, j) / A(1, j)
        mag = sqrt(real(A(1, j)*conjg(A(1, j)))+ real(A(2, j)*conjg(A(2, j))))
        A(:, j) = A(:, j)/mag
     end do

     psi1a = A(1, 1)
     psi1b = A(1, 2)
     psi2a = A(2, 1)
     psi2b = A(2, 2)

  end do
end program Eigenvalue
```

Comment: I would explicitly strate that you did not observe any discontinuities. It is in the comments above, but it is somewhat hidden and people may wonder what message are you trying to convey.

Comment: @VladimirF Done. Took a bit of work, but now I actually understand the issue. It's a more mathematical problem as Ian mentioned above.

Comment: @muddle Thanks for the code, I compiled it now by following your instructions, and I did not observer any discontinuities.

Comment: @muddle Just for completeness the above is better but you will still have problems in the general case if a( 1, j ) is zero or you have degenerate eigenvalues. In the latter case it is because again you have an arbitrary quantity, in this case because any linear combination of the evecs is still an evec, so the computer can choose any pair it likes in the plane. However in this specific case I don't think this is ever an issue due to the form of the matrix. And enjoy working for NAG, I was there until a couple of years ago!